# Marker not showing in google maps

Tags: android, dictionary, marker

I have created a google map fragment in android but marker is not showing. Map is showing perfectly but not marker,  And how can I set user current location as marker ?

```
   public class GoogleMap extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap googleMap;
    private static final LatLng Ahmedabad = new LatLng(23.022214, 72.542786);

    public GoogleMap() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_google_map, container, false);



        processMap(v);

        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
    }


    public void processMap(View v) {
        if (googleMap != null) {

            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Ahmedabad).title("Ahmedabad"));


            // TODO: Consider calling


        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should call **processMap(v)** after the map ready. when you tried to call processMap onCreateView, your google map is not ready yet , your googleMap variable is null

```
private com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap googleMap;
private static final LatLng Ahmedabad = new LatLng(23.022214, 72.542786);

public GoogleMap() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_google_map, container, false);

    return v;

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap;
    processMap();
}    

public void processMap() {
    if (googleMap != null) {

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Ahmedabad).title("Ahmedabad"));

    }
}
```

Comment: processMap() requires argument 'v' but if I write then it says cannot resolve symbol

Comment: I already edit your processMap
Please look at my code wholefully